# diasble- grey out import data for SQL server and import data from web server in power bi desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I work in project and we want that all user use direct query (live connection from SQL server) we want to grey out the import mode so they can not import data for security purposes.

Do you know also if there is  a way to grey out import data from web.

[grey out import data in sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtkbW.png)   [grey out get data from web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAod6.png), we just use power bi desktop and power bi report server (on-premises), any insights

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know there is only an option to deactivate direct query connections. you can set it in the options pane as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

Import is the default storage mode used by BI vertipaq engine.

Comment: thanks do you know if we can grey-out the option import from web?

Comment: I know that you can't do that inside power bi option settings. Logically, The strength of Power BI comes from connecting various data sources and importing & compressing data, including web source. Disabling such a feature can't be a consideration for the software.